# If condition in php strange situation

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have found a strange situation in php...or maybe I don't remember something well:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["invio"]) && ($_POST["valore1"] && $_POST["valore2"])) {

        if($_POST["valore1"]) {
        $valore1 = $_POST["valore1"];
        }
        if($_POST["valore2"]) {
        $valore2 = $_POST["valore2"];
        }


        function pippo ($x,$y) {

        if($x < $y) {
        return "la variabile $x è minore della variabile $y";
        }
        elseif($x == $y) {
        return "la variabile $x è uguale alla variabile $y";
        }
        else {
        return "la variabile $x è più grande rispetto alla variabile $y";
        }
        }

        $risultato = pippo($valore1,$valore2);

        print $risultato;

}elseif (isset($_POST["invio"]) && ($_POST["valore1"] =="" || $_POST["valore2"] =="") ) {
        print "Manca almeno un valore";
        }
```

If I try to delete the two parentheses:

```
}elseif (isset($_POST["invio"]) && $_POST["valore1"] =="" || $_POST["valore2"] =="" ) {
        print "Manca almeno un valore";
        }
```

The system enters inside the condition with the print.. why does it do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AND has [higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than OR so

```
a && b || c
```

is interpreted as

```
(a && b) || c
```

Not as

```
a && (b || c)
```

AND is the boolean version of multiplication -- `(0 AND 1)` is 0 just like `(0 * 1)` is 0.

OR is like addition -- `(0 OR 1)` is 1 just as `(0 + 1)` is 1.

`A * B + C` would also be understood as `(A * B) + C`.